# I need to InsertBefore or InsertAfter in the parent not the child

Tags: c#, xml, nodes, xmldocument, xmlnodelist

Here's my Xml

```
<root>
<categories>
    <recipe id="RecipeID2">
        <name>something 1</name>
    </recipe>
    <recipe id="RecipeID2">
        <name>something 2</name>
    </recipe>
    <recipe id="RecipeID3">
        <name>something 3</name>
    </recipe>
</categories>
</root>
```

I'm parsing all recipes where the client want to insert the new recipe after or before

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

xmlDocument.Load("thexmlfiles.xml");

XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("/root/categories//Recipe");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    if (node.Attributes["id"].InnerText == comboBoxInsertRecipe.Text)
    {
        node.InsertAfter(xfrag, node.ChildNodes[0]);
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
<root>
<categories>
    <recipe id="RecipeID2">
        <name>something 1</name>
    </recipe>
    <recipe id="RecipeID2">
        <name>something 2</name>
    </recipe>
    <recipe id="NewRecipe4">
        <name>new Recipe 4</name>
    </recipe>
    <recipe id="RecipeID3">
        <name>something 3</name>
    </recipe>
</categories>
</root>
```

but when I insert my new recipes its does like this

```
<root>
<categories>
    <recipe id="RecipeID2">
        <name>something 1</name>
    </recipe>
    <recipe id="RecipeID2">
        <name>something 2</name>
    </recipe>
    <recipe id="RecipeID3">
        <name>something 3</name>
        <recipe id="NewRecipe4">
            <name>new Recipe 4</name>
        </recipe>
    </recipe>
</categories>
</root>
```

The new recipe is inside another recipe but not inside the categories

Comment: You're selecting all the `<Recipe>` nodes into the `nodes` list - so of course, if you add something to such a node, it will be inside that `<recipe>` node. You need to do the insert to the **parent** of your recipe node - something like: `node.parent.Insert(....);`

Answer (score 2):

First, I recommend using [LINQ-to-Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688087.aspx). Sample of L2Xml in this answer.

```
XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load("thexmlfiles.xml");
var root = xmlDocument.Root;
var recipes = root.Element("categories").Elements("recipe");
```

Second, get a handle/reference to the node you wish to insert before/after.

```
var currentRecipe = recipes.Where(r => r.Attribute("id") == "RecipeID3")
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

... then add as appropriate (using [`XElement.AddAfterSelf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.addafterself%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`XElement.AddBeforeSelf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.addbeforeself%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
void AddNewRecipe(XElement NewRecipe, bool IsAfter, XElement CurrentRecipe) {
   if(IsAfter) {
      CurrentRecipe.AddAfterSelf(NewRecipe);
   } else {
      CurrentRecipe.AddBeforeSelf(NewRecipe);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the new node at the wrong document level. The element has to be added (as pointed) to the *category* node and not to a *sibling* node. You have two options to find the correct node and then to add the node to the correct position:

- as you do it, iterating over all nodes looking for a match
- find the node directly using XPath **/path/element[@attribute='attributeName']**

An example that adds the node to the correct position looks like this:

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(@"d:\temp\thexmlfile.xml");
XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("/root/categories/recipe");
// root node
XmlNodeList category = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("/root/categories");
// test node for the example
var newRecipe = xmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "recipe", "");
var newInnerNode = xmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "name", "");
newInnerNode.InnerText = "test";
var attribute = xmlDocument.CreateAttribute("id");
attribute.Value = "RecipeID4";
newRecipe.Attributes.Append(attribute);
newRecipe.AppendChild(newInnerNode);
// variant 1; find node while iteration over all nodes
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    if (node.Attributes["id"].InnerText == "RecipeID3")
    {
        // insert into the root node after the found node
        category[0].InsertAfter(newRecipe, node);
    }
}
// variant 2; use XPath to select the element with the attribute directly
//category[0].InsertAfter(newRecipe, xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/root/categories/recipe[@id='RecipeID3']"));
// 
xmlDocument.Save(@"d:\temp\thexmlfileresult.xml");
```

The output is:

```
<root>
    <categories>
        <recipe id="RecipeID1">
            <name>something 1</name>
        </recipe>
        <recipe id="RecipeID2">
            <name>something 2</name>
        </recipe>
        <recipe id="RecipeID3">
            <name>something 3</name>
        </recipe>
        <recipe id="RecipeID4">
            <name>test</name>
        </recipe>
    </categories>
</root>
```

As also suggested you could make this with LINQ2XML. The code can look like this:

```
// load document ...
var xml = XDocument.Load(@"d:\temp\thexmlfile.xml");
// find node and add new one after it
xml.Root                        // from root
    .Elements("categories")     // find categories
    .Elements("recipe")         // all recipe nodes
    .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Attribute("id").Value == "RecipeID3")    // find node by attribute
    .AddAfterSelf(new XElement("recipe",                            // create new recipe node
                    new XAttribute("id", "RecipeID4"),              // with attribute
                    new XElement("name", "test")));                 // and content - name node
// and save document ...
xml.Save(@"d:\temp\thexmlfileresult.xml");
```

The output is the same. LINQ2XML is in many ways easier and comfortable to use than XmlDocument. For example selection of subnodes could be a lot easier and you don't need the XPath string:

```
xml.Descendants("recipe");
```

[LINQ2XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) it's worth it to give it a try.